# VB.Net How to move the app.config file to a custom location

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I have an application that has a load of values in its app.exe.config file. The application is used by a few users, and the settings would change on a regular basis. so im having to change the config file, and send it out to all users.

I'd love to move the config file to the network somewhere and point the app to this file. ive tried to use;

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

OpenExeConfiguration("I:\app config\HelpDeskQuickCallLogger.exe.config")
```

But i cant get it to read in the values.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: i've never run into this sort of thing-- but it's a good question. Can you use some other stream reader/file reader method to open up a file on the network drive?

Comment: The documentation is clear that the method expects the path of the `exe`.

Comment: Every time I have needed something similar I rolled my own config file. And didn't use the app.config file. What type of data are you storing in the file?

Comment: Its a helpdesk call logging software, the file contains a list a call catogorys, engineers names, ldap info, smtp info. stuff that can change that i dont want to hard code. I like the app.config as its just one line to get the data out of it.

Comment: @ek_ny i suppose im going to have to go down that route if i cant move the config file. can you point me in any direction to get me started?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but see if this Code Project [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/CustomSettingsProvider.aspx?msg=3424827) helps.

Description from above article:

> This article demonstrates how to write a custom Settings Provider to
>   allow you to persist your My.Settings to your own storage system.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we handle this requirement if a specific configuration file (sSpecificConfigurationFile) is specified:

```
    Dim oConfig As System.Configuration.Configuration

    If sSpecificConfigurationFile.EndsWith(".config", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        Dim oMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap
        oMap.ExeConfigFilename = sSpecificConfigurationFile
        oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(oMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Else
        oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(sSpecificConfigurationFile)
    End If
```